# How to finish Activity when all AsynTask complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have three `AsyncTasks` in my Splash screen `Activity` that downloads app data for caching.  I don't want to actually start the next Activity until all `task`'s finish.

Is there an effective way of doing this?

Here is how I call my Tasks in the `onCreate`:

```
            TrendingTask task = new TrendingTask(SplashActivity.this);
            task.execute();

            TrendingWatchingTask task2 = new TrendingWatchingTask(
                    SplashActivity.this);
            task2.execute();

            new MasterTask().execute();
```

They are all called, one after the other.  I don't actually start the next Activity until it gets to the `onPostExecute()` in `MasterTask`.  But I believe this is a gamble cause the other two may not be finished.

Note:  `MasterTask` is an inner `class` while the other two are their own classes.

Comment: You can be sure if all your asynctasks are finished by looking if they run serially or parallel. This has been changed a couple of times according to your API level. Check out this post (starting in the middle) for more information: http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a global integer counter and increment it every time an AsyncTask starts(in its onPreExecute()) and decrement it in onPostExecute(). And when you launch your activity you can check if this counter is equal to zero. If it isn't - then you know you've got AsyncTasks running.

Comment: While this might sound fairly reasonable at first glance, how are you going to keep checking before launching your activity? Do you keep checking in a loop? Assuming you're looping in a non-UI thread, if you increment in `onPreExecute` and decrement in `onPostExecute`, your check might come inbetween two `AsyncTask`s at which time the counter will be 0, but in fact your tasks are not all complete.